# Camera and microphone doesn't work in zoom

Tags: webcam, microphone

I have installed zoom for school purposes and it detects the camera and the microphone, and they work when i test them in configuration, but when I join a meeting they suddenly stop working. They are still being recognized but they don't work.

Is there any solution to this?

Thanks

Comment: How are you testing them?

Comment: I'm testing them through the configuration of zoom, there is an option to check both of them, and also I checked both of them in configuration of Ubuntu, in case that the system is the problem, but it looks like zoom is the problem

Comment: Try the Ubuntu app Cheese since you are testing with the same program that does not seem to fully work.

Comment: I have already done that

Comment: It works on cheese

Comment: OK then its not something that can be helped here. I would suggest to go to the zoom support site and get the help there. https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us

Comment: Thank you for your time and help kind sir!

Comment: I don't know how to do it

Comment: Nevermind, just did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK then its not something that can be helped here. I would suggest to go to the zoom support site and get the help there. support.zoom.us/hc/en-us – David 1 hour ago

Comment: thanks very much